# Visual Studio, Docker and Docker-Compose practices

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to understand the best way to use Docker and Visual Studio.

As I understand it,
By selecting the application in the startup-project and Docker as the executable tool, whenever I debug my application, I am debugging in the container of the application. This container is empty unless I am debugging.

By publishing to a Docker hub, I am creating a container that can be run without Visual Studio and I can set other parameters such as the name and the port.

What does the docker-compose do? If I set the startup-project to docker-compose, how is that different to what I have just done? Does it set the name and port and can it merge containers into one.

I will eventually have a web application in a container, a MySQL container and I will want to share it with testers and put it into production.

What are the general processes I need to follow?

Answer (score 1):

1. Every container can be run outside of Visual Studio, it is used to debug your application (while it runs inside a container). I personally like to test the app outside VS to see if the docker and docker-compose files work correctly for deploying the app
2. When you publish to Docker hub, you don't create a container, you create an image (which then can be run inside a container).
3. Docker-compose is used to run multiple related projects (e.g. API and Website client). It does everything docker does but on bigger scale (added bonus, you can have neat files for running the apps and don't need to play with scripts or terminal that much). Having a Webapp and MySQl containers is a standard use case for this tool.
4. When you want to make different versions for testers and production you can use multiple docker-compose files, in which you can use different setups for each one.

When it comes to the processes it all depends on your situation.

- You can have some pipelines set to build the images when you push code to a repository (if you have resources to maintain this)
- You can build the images yourself and push them directly to image repository (like docker hub)
- The same thing goes to deploying the app once you have the images, you can have automatic builds or do to the server and deploy it yourself.

One thing to remember is to effectively use image tags for versioning